# Error creating VPC: UnauthorizedOperation

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, vpc

I am trying to create VPC by using terraform, I am using IAM user's secrate and access key for authentication.
But when trying to create VPC it is throwing "Error creating VPC: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: <encode_message>"
When I decode this message then I got it's don't have permission to ec2:createVpc. But I have assign Administrator Access, ec2 full access and vpc full access to this user.
I am able to create any other resources by using this credentials.

Really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this is your own account, or part some AWS Organization?

Comment: Could you share your terraform code?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you have properly setup your AWS credential on your local development environment either with environment variables like `AWS_*` or the shared credential file `~/.aws/credentials` (I am assuming that you're on Linux).

If not, see the official documentation from AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html

(I assume you have `aws-cli` installed, if not then see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html)

Then, to check if your credential is properly configured, you can try with this command:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

You should see something like:

```
{
    "UserId": "<REDACTED>",
    "Account": "<REDACTED>",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::<REDACTED>:<REDACTED>"
}
```

Remember not to share the output above!

Answer (score 0):

Your user may not have the necessary permissions to perform the action.

Try adding something like the following to your permissions:

```
{
    "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
    "Resource": "*"
},
{
    "Sid": "foo",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateVpc",
        "ec2:DeleteVpc"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These can be 1 possible cause:

1. After making sure its not `~/.aws/credentials` one possible cause is check if you have a MFA policy set which can be the blocker as well.

For me , I temporarily removed the permission related to MFA and worked.

**I figure out the issue by decoding the error message from the response with following command and knew it was MFA:**

```
aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message <code-here>
```

Now you get to see the cause of the problem